# Суть класса clearFix

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, float

Не могу понять класс `clearfix`.

Что он делает? Какой смысл несёт?

Я понял, что он используется в связке с `float`, но вот как и что делает — не ясно.

Буду благодарен за подробное объяснение с примером до и после, чтобы увидеть наглядно какую проблему он решает.

Comment: сбрасывает значение флоатов

Comment: ассоциация: [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8554043/2881286)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Следующая картинка поможет понять, что делает **clearfix**.

[image]

<sub>Перевод ответа [@kyo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29562362/2881286)</sub>

Comment: ?а можно ли описание  к картине

Comment: @elik, на ней в принципе все показано: контейнер `div` в котором два `float` элемента, в первом случае контейнер схлопывается, во втором - нет. В идеале конечно добавить перевод отмеченного ответа, но он большой :-) а на этом сразу видно различие :)